# "Error:Cant fidn the necesary file - How to Resolve and Successfully Update?

Tags: windows, operating-system, upgrade

Each time I try to open the windows .exe to upgrade it I get this error>
[image]

How can I fix this error that happens when I open the windows10upgrade 9252?

I want to upgrade Windows because docker is asking me to do that

I get this error while trying to upgrade windows 10

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the program as an administrator because it doesn't have the permission to actually write files to the windows installation folder.

Comment: does not work... I get the same error

Comment: What program are you running exactly?